# Isabelle/HOL tutorial/documentation needed

Tags: isabelle

I am looking for freely available and good quality tutorials and documentation for Isabelle2013/HOL (aside of the obvious ones after Google-ing and digging a bit). Could you please recommend some?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: @KenWhite: Well, my question is programming related (very much), the entire ATP area is scattered over the entire web, lots of different approaches, different tools, syntaxes, etc. I am willing to get any opinionated answers, as any opinionated answer is better than no answer. :-) This is not Java or C#, where you throw a stone and hit ten programmers...

Comment: Still off topic, according to the [On topic pages in the Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Scarcity or difficulty in locating doesn't magically turn an off-topic post into on-topic. The guideline that I quoted is quite clear, as is the heading it's posted under in Help: "Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:"

Comment: @KenWhite: Please help me then to make it more on topic. I would like to do ATP to do proofs on programming languages. The end result is code, adhering to formal syntax. The code will be used in mission critical systems. The entire ATP area is very opinionated, lots of small groups, lots of closed-group discussion, diverse tools, no industry backing. L4.verified is one completed work. You probably could not show one other. So yes, the entire software lifecycle requires a Vision, Explorarory, Feasibility Test actions, and those development which do not do this __ARE__ off-topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some documents that may help get you started:

- The previous de-facto tutorial was [A Proof Assistant for Higher-Order Logic](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/tutorial.pdf) by Nipkow, Paulson and Wenzel. This document provides an introduction to Isabelle/HOL as a functional programming language as well as a guide as to how to use most of the common proof mechanisms available in Isabelle/HOL. It is a good starting point;
- A newer tutorial is [Programming and Proving in Isabelle/HOL](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/prog-prove.pdf) by Nipkow. It covers some of the same material as the previous document and is not quite as in-depth, but uses more modern techniques of carrying out proofs in Isabelle/HOL. It may be useful as a "quick-start" to Isabelle/HOL.
- The freely available book [Concrete Semantics](http://www21.in.tum.de/~nipkow/Concrete-Semantics/) by Nipkow and Klein provides an introduction to Isabelle/HOL in the context of performing proofs on programming languages. If your interest in Isabelle/HOL is to do with program verification, this book would be a good start.

Is general, most (but not all) good reference guides are linked to from the [Isabelle documentation page](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/documentation.html) itself. watch out, however, as some of the documents there are quite old and unlikely to be relevant any longer, (though such documents have been tagged as such).

There are also a plethora of slides and lecture notes available of the web, such as [UNSW](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~cs4161/11s2/lect.html) or the [University of Edinburgh](http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/ar/slides/index.html), but these are probably better used as a supplement, as they often lack context and important details which are provided in the lectures.

Comment: Thank you @davidg, these links seem promising, the "Concrete Semantics" link is a particularly useful one.